# Not matching sample in y axis for knn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, knn

Im trying to make my way to a sligthly more flexible knn input script than the tutorials based of the iris dataset but Im having some trouble (I think) to add the matching 2nd dimension to the numpy array in #6 and when I come to #11. the fitting.

> File "G:\PROGRAMMERING\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [150, 1]

x is (150,5) and y is (150,1). 150 is the number of samples in both, but they differ in number of fields, is this the problem and if so how do I fix it?

````
#1. Loading the Pandas libraries as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#2. Read data from the file 'custom.csv' placed in your code directory
data = pd.read_csv("custom.csv") 

#3. Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
print(data.head())
print(type(data))

#4.Test the shape of the data
print(data.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

#5. Convert non-numericals to numericals
print(df.dtypes)
# Any object should be converted to numerical
df['species'] = pd.Categorical(df['species'])
df['species'] = df.species.cat.codes
print("outcome:")
print(df.dtypes)

#6.Convert df to numpy.ndarray
np = df.to_numpy()
print(type(np)) #this should state <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(data.shape) 
print(np)
x = np.data
y = [df['species']]
print(y)

#K-nearest neighbor (find closest) - searach for the K nearest observations in the dataset
#The model calculates the distance to all, and selects the K nearest ones.
#8. Import the class you plan to use
from sklearn.neighbors import (KNeighborsClassifier)
#9. Pick a value for K
k = 2
#10. Instantiate the "estimator" (make an instance of the model)
knn  = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
print(knn)
#11. fit the model with data/model training
knn.fit(x, y)
#12. Predict the response for a new observation
print(knn.predict([[3, 5, 4, 2]]))```
````

Comment: ```def check_consistent_length(*arrays):
    """Check that all arrays have consistent first dimensions.
    Checks whether all objects in arrays have the same shape or length.
    Parameters
    ----------
    *arrays : list or tuple of input objects.
        Objects that will be checked for consistent length.
    """
    lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    if len(uniques) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
                        " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input prediction input is 4 columns, leaving the fifth 'species' without prediction. Also, if 'species' was the target it cannot be given as input to the knn at the same time. The pop removes this particular column from the dataFrame df.

```
#npdf = df.to_numpy()
df = df.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
y = np.asarray(df['species'])
#removes the target from the sample
df.pop('species')
x = df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used the `scikit-learn KNeighborsClassifier` to fit the `knn` model:

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

df = datasets.load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(df.data)
y = df.target
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 2)
knn.fit(X,y)
print(knn.predict([[6, 3, 5, 2]]))
#prints output class [2]
print(knn.predict([[3, 5, 4, 2]]))
#prints output class [1]
```

From `DataFrame` you don't need to convert to `numpy array`, you can directly fit the model on `DataFrame`, also while converting the `DataFrame` to `numpy array` you have named that as `np` which is also used to import `numpy` at the top `import numpy as np`

Comment: Thanks, I already had that. Problem was that load_iris only loads the iris but no custom dataset. My setup is now flexible enough to load any dataset with some tweaks in #5 and #6.